# Similar seaborn plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

i want experimenting all plots in seaborn with R 
for that i want plot similar seaborn plot in R
but i am unable to fulfill the exact similar graph in R
[seaborn graph](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#navbar)

my updated R code is

```
x = seq(from = 0,to = 14,length.out = 100)
for(i in seq(1,6)){
    print(sin(x + i * .5)*(7 - i))
    plot(x,sin(x + i * .5)*(7 - i))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is creating a new plot each time through the loop. Use `lines` to add a line to an existing plot.

```
plot(x, sin(x + 1 * .5)*(7 - 1), type="l")
for(i in seq(2,6)) {
  lines(x, sin(x + i * .5)*(7 - i), col=i)
}
```

[image]

You could also do this with `ggplot2`:

```
library(tidyverse)  # loads several related packages including ggplot2 and purrr, both of which we use below.

my_fun = function(x, i) {
  sin(x + i  * .5)*(7 - i)
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=x), aes(x)) + 
  map2(1:6, hcl(seq(15,375,length=7)[1:6],100,65), function(ii,cc) {
  stat_function(fun=my_fun, args=list(i=ii), col=cc)
  }) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the ggplot2

```
 x = seq(from = 0,to = 14,length.out = 100)

        p <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x), aes(x = x,y = sin(x + 1 * .5)*(7 - 1) ))+geom_line()

        for (i in 2:6) {

           p <- p + geom_line(aes_string(y = sin(x + i * .5)*(7 - i)),col  = i)+
                      theme_classic()+theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())

         }
       p
```